# Comparing data types

Tags: c++, types, comparison

```
int item;
cin >> item;
```

That's in my code, but I want the user to be able to type integers or strings. This is basically what I want to do:

```
if(item.data_type() == string){
  //stuff
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, but you can input string and then convert it to integer, if it is integer.

Comment: This is what I was looking for - how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do exactly that, but with a little more work you can do something similar.  The following code works if you have the Boost libraries installed.  It can be done without boost, but its tedious to do so.

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

main() {
    std::string val;
    std::cout << "Value: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> val;
    try {
        int i = boost::lexical_cast<int>(val);
        std::cout << "It's an integer: " << i << std::endl;
    }
    catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast &blc) {
        std::cout << "It's not an integer" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this articles:

[Use RTTI for Dynamic Type Identification](http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/Article/10202/1954)

[C++ Programming/RTTI](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/RTTI)

[Run-time type information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information)

Comment: RTTI lets him identify the type of am object. I don't think this will help for his situation. The string "123" is still a string as far as RTTI is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is not value C++ code. It wouldn't compile!

---

Your problem is:

> That's in my code, but I want the user to be able to type integers or strings

Then do this:

```
std::string input;
cin >> input;
int intValue;
std::string strValue;
bool isInt=false;
try 
{   
    intValue = boost::lexical_cast<int>(input);
    isInt = true;
}
catch(...) { strValue = input; }

if ( isInt) 
{
   //user input was int, so use intValue;
}
else
{
   //user input was string, so use strValue;
}
```

Comment: I've got boost installed, but I don't want to use it for this small RPG that runs in command.